# Does ZMQ have a mechanism to tell whether a connection is still alive?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a ZMQ server that performs a heavy computation and thus sending the result back to the client via `server_socket.send()` can take several minutes. The client should wait indefinitely for the result of the computation. However, if the connection drops during the computation, then the client should find another server to connect to.

I know this could be implemented manually by using a background thread on the server that keeps sending "please wait" messages to the client until the result is ready. This way, the client can use `client_socket.RCVTIMEO = 1000` to raise `zmq.Again` if the server does not respond within 1 second.

However, I'm wondering whether there is a built-in mechanism in ZMQ for this, because it already uses background threads itself to send and receive messages. Is there a mechanism in ZMQ to tell whether a connection is still alive even though the server code has not called `server_socket.send()` in a while?

Here is the manual solution (which also only works for the case of a single client for now) that I would like to simplify:

```
import threading
import time

import zmq


def server():

  context = zmq.Context.instance()
  socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
  socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')

  while True:

    identity, _, message = socket.recv_multipart()
    print('Received request from client')

    print('Start telling the client to wait')
    waiting = True
    def say_wait():
      while waiting:
        socket.send_multipart([identity, b'', b'wait'])
        time.sleep(0.1)
        # TODO: This also needs to get a message from the same client, not any.
        _, _, message = socket.recv_multipart()
        assert message == b'alright', message

    thread = threading.Thread(target=say_wait)
    thread.start()

    print('Perform heavy server computation')
    time.sleep(3)

    print('Stop telling the client to wait')
    waiting = False
    thread.join()

    print('Send the result to the client')
    socket.send_multipart([identity, b'', b'result'])


def client():

  socket = None

  while True:

    if not socket:
      print('Client finds a new server to connect to')
      context = zmq.Context.instance()
      socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
      socket.RCVTIMEO = 1000  # 1 second timeout.
      address = find_available_server()
      socket.connect(f'tcp://{address}')

    socket.send(b'request')
    try:
      while True:
        message = socket.recv()
        if message == b'wait':
          print('Client heard that it should wait longer')
          socket.send(b'alright')
          continue
        else:
          print(f'Client got the result of the computation: {message}')
          break
    except zmq.Again:
      print('Client did not hear back from the server')
      socket.close(linger=0)
      socket = None


def find_available_server():
  # In practice, this function asks a central coordinator for
  # the IP address of an available server.
  return 'localhost:5555'


threading.Thread(target=server).start()
threading.Thread(target=client).start()
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no such functionality. In general, you can only tell if a network peer is still alive when there is actually data flowing through the network. You could enable TCP keepalive though.

Comment: @rveerd Thanks for the pointer! I found that there is ZMQ_TCP_KEEPALIVE to enable TCP keepalive (by default it depends on the OS). Do you know how I can then ask ZMQ whether the TCP connection is alive?

Comment: If TCP keepalive detects that the peer is no longer alive any send or receive call will then return an error directly.

Comment: @rveerd Great, that would be sufficient for my use case. What error is thrown in that case? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: For a normal TCP socket, that would be `ECONNRESET` (Connection reset by peer) or `EPIPE` (Broken pipe). Not sure what ZeroMQ returns or what the Python alternative is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look a the ZMQ_HEARTBEAT socket options, with socket monitor. Turn this option on, and the library will constantly ping the connection to and fro. If one end unexpectedly disappears, you get to learn about that at the surviving end via socket monitor.

Certainly, this option exists in C/C++ bindings. I don't know for sure about the pyzmq library, but I'd be surprised if it didn't support it. It'd have to understand heart beat pings from other implementations; it has no option but to at least comply with the protocol standard. If so, why not expose the the functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can use zmq `socket monitor` to detect events like connection accepts/disconnects.

API - http://api.zeromq.org/4-3:zmq-socket-monitor

Python example - https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/main/examples/monitoring/simple_monitor.py

Comment: That probably will not work when the connection is not properly closed, for example, when the client dies or the TCP connection is dropped because of network issues.

Comment: Thanks! In my use case, the client needs to detect whether the server is still available, not the other way around. I think the monitor events may only work for the server to detect client connects/disconnects? Also, do you know if disconnect events are sent when the TCP connection dies because the other side went down unexpectedly?

Comment: When you add a Monitor to socket (Client), then all the events for the SOCKET are returned. These include CONNECT, RETRY, DISCONNECT, HANDSHAKE. Thus, if the server entity is unreachable due to a Network Glitch, the Client Socket will throw these Events.